# How convert link description to valid file name

Tags: c#, .net

there is a library or a code that convert a link description to valid file name?

Example:

```
<a href="">This is my description link</a>
```

I want to convert "This is my description link" for example in "ThisIsMyDescriptionLink" and save it in my database. This will be the name of the file displayed (and saved) in case of download.

Il must work with any operating system like windows, android or mac....

Thank you.

Sara

Comment: Spaces are valid in filenames on most systems.

Comment: Yes, I know. But is only an example :-). There could be characters like : / < etc

Comment: You will need a split character (say a space as in the example) and then you could use a simple .replace(" ","\\") on the string.

Comment: Yes, my idea is replace space and then replace invalid characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's `Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()` method that can be used to replace invalid file name characters like this:

```
using System.IO;
....
string description = "This is my description link with <invalid characters>";
char[] invalidChars = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars();

foreach (var c in invalidChars )
{
    description = description.Replace(c.ToString(), ""); 
}
```

Or with LINQ:

```
description = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars().
Aggregate("This is my description link with <invalid characters>",
(current, c) => current.Replace(c.ToString(), ""));
```

Comment: Thank you @Mikhail. The method `Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()` find also invalid char in Mac or Android system? (I'm not practice for these systems)

Comment: This method available in Mono, so it can be used on Mac. It's also available in Xamarin, thus in Android.